# How to find out what an action is called in gimp's Batch Image Manipulation?

Tags: gimp, batch, image-processing, photo-editing

I want to both zealous crop and remove image transparency for a bunch of files. I know how to start the batch job and I was able to find the action `plug-in-zealouscrop` for--duh--zeahlous crop. Yet I cannot seem to find the correct GIMP procedure name for remvoving transparency.

I tried doing the action manually and looking in the journal, but it also does not reveal much specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gimp-image-flatten` for the whole image (this also merges all layers), or `gimp-layer-flatten` to remove the transparency of a single layer.